# Xamarin Forms: Plugin.MediaManager & Plugin.MediaManager.Forms don't display the video in XAML VideoView

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugin.mediamanager.forms

I want to substitute `XCT:MediaElement` with `Plugin.MediaManger & Plugin.MediaManager.Forms` for my videos to play cross-platform. [Documentation](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#usage) I've read this like 5 times and it still doesn't make any sense. I'm putting my video into `Assets` in `Android` and using `XAML` code below. The picture is the output I get on the screen, it's just a black background which I can change to any color...

I've added the `Init()` to the `MainActivity` and also to the `AppDelegate`. Followed everything step by step.

What really doesn't make any sense from the documentation is (Examples). `CrossMediaManager` is a static class. I cannot create a new instance of static classes so I cannot actually assign anything to the `layout`. How does it suppose to play anything on the screen if there is nothing that can actually consume this?

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromAssembly("somefile.mp3", typeof(BaseViewModel).Assembly);
await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromResource("assets:///somefile.mp3");
await CrossMediaManager.Android.PlayFromResource(Resource.Raw.somefile.ToString());
```

Further, on the documentation you come across the [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#xamarinforms) part where it shows how to do this is `XAML` with `mm:ViewView` now this makes more sense and I can also assign an `x:Name` to it and pass through `MVVM` pattern through the `Behind Code` to the `ViewModel` and so on, but this would be cool if the video played in the first place...

Any idea why this is happening?
Many Thanks in Advance.

**Nuget Packges I've added**: `Plugin.MediaManager` & `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms`

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                WidthRequest="400"
                HeightRequest="600"
                Margin="10"
                Padding="20">
    <mm:VideoView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Source="assets:///pea2.mp4"
                    AutoPlay="True"
                    ShowControls="True" />
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/840

Comment: @Jason okay so I've read that but still not of any help as it doesn't say how on earth a static class binds to the view and plays a video...? `await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/long-test.mp3");` I'm awaiting a IMediaItem here that contains `MetaData`... I don't want `MetaData` I want to see the video play on the screen.

Comment: Have you looked at the samples?  Or read https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#add-video-player-to-the-ui

Comment: I have test it on the android 11, the vedio can play successfully. But on the andorid 12, I met the same problem as yours. And on the ios, the vedio control view will show but the vedio didn't display. And there is [an issue about the plugin doesn't work on the android 12](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/876).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT thanks for that, but at this point, I don't even understand how the whole thing works at all. I've spent last night 3 hours trying to figure out how the whole things binds together and I just don't understand what on earth is going on with this `Plugin`. Is it possible you can write and answer of step by step of how to get it to work because after investing [AndroidSamples](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/tree/develop/Samples/AndroidPlayerSample) I got even more confused...

Comment: I didn't try the local mp4 file, I tested it with a mp4 file in the website.

Comment: I will take that if possible, I will figure out the rest I just want to see the video play in the first place and after that, I will start to break it down from top to bottom. Otherwise, I'm just hitting a brick wall ATM. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first, I install the `Plugin.MediaManger & Plugin.MediaManager.Forms` two packages in all the project, such as PCL(forms part), android part and ios part.

And then I added the following code in the MainActivity:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                  CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
            CrossMediaManager.Current.AutoPlay = true;
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

And in the MainPage.Xaml:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <mm:VideoView VideoAspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="https://www.appsloveworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/sample-mp4-video.mp4" ShowControls="True"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

And here is the result image on the android 11 emulator:

[image]

**Note**, according to the issue I mentioned in the comments, the plugin will work on the android 12 after adding the `CrossMediaManager.Current.Speed = 1F;`. But it will throw exception when I added it. It's strange.

Comment: I'm running into an identical issue. Big F. Do you potentially know of any other packages for `Xamarin.Forms` that play videos on both platforms without flashing black on loading the video to the screen like `Xamarin.Communitytoolkit`. Sorry for long response focused on developer other aspects and not be stuck on this.

Comment: All right, did you try to use the [mediaelement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement). @ThisQRequiresASpecialist

Comment: Yeah, `MediaElement` is the one that causes all the issues for me. It keeps blinking black when loading a new screen. That's why I tried finding a new package. Unless you maybe could help me figure out how I can pre-load a video before the next screen is shown. I know the exact sequence in which videos will play.

Comment: What does `blinking black when loading a new screen` mean? Did you try to use the custom renderer to get the effect you want? @ThisQRequiresASpecialist

Comment: What I mean is that once a new screen load the video player stars flashing black for 1 seconds before the video plays. Or the video stutters loads of times and just constantly restarts and IDK why but if I have more than 1 `MediaElement` they don't actually listen correctly to their properties. I've made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74138061/xamarin-community-toolkit-mediaelement-flashes-black-on-load-android-problem-onl) about this. I will try 1 more thing right now by creating a `VideoLoader` to load the next video into memory before page shows.

Comment: You can try to use the platforms' player to display the video with the dependency service.