# Xamarin Forms: Video is not working on Android version 12 and above with MediaElement

Tags: xamarin.forms, nullpointerexception, mediaelement

I am using `MediaElement` for playing video in my xamarin forms application. It is working fine on android version 11 and below. But on android version 12 and above, after playing a video, if we tap on the pause option, the app breaks with the below exception:

**Exception:**

> [InputEventReceiver] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
> [InputEventReceiver]    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:636)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14964)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6992)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6758)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6208)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6275)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6236)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6409)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6244)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6466)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6212)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6275)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6236)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6244)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6212)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9339)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:9290)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9234)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:9480)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:276)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:339)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
> [InputEventReceiver]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)

**My Versions:**

Xamarin forms: 5.0.0.2291

Xamarin.CommunityToolkit: 1.3.1

Visual Studio: 17.4.3

**I tried updating the xamarin toolkit package to the latest, but no luck. Is it a known issue?**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74809484/4308455

Comment: For this problem,you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues) .

Comment: @ewerspej My issue is different

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Reported https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1943

Comment: Thanks for your support for maui and feedback.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I added `CrossMediaManager.Current.Speed = 1F;` before playing audio, and now audio is working fine. But for video, it is playing well, but the pause option breaks the application.